# Confused about not losing data in Hyper-V VMs

Tags: windows-server-2008, hyper-v

I am new to Hyper-V and have managed to lose all the changes I made to a VM.  I can't quite tell what exact steps I took to lose the data, but I think it involved shutting down the VM.  And then, it basically went back to its original state.

So, I do have the VM running and it is in the right state and running right now.  And here is its screenshot.

[image]

In the Snapshots pane, I can right click on either Tally1 or Renamed Base and click on `Apply...`.  I want to save the current state to be my master.  How do I do that?

Comment: What do you mean "be my master"? You want to get rid of the snapshots? You can not make the machines current state the pared of existing snapshots, that would make no sense.

Comment: @ChrisS The state of the machine right now, as it is running... when I shut it down and restart it again (or take the VHD elsewhere), I want it to be in the same state as it is now.

Comment: You will never lose anything by shutting a VM down or restarting it in Hyper-V. The only way you could lose something is by reverting a snapshot without saving the current state, or by mucking about in Hyper-V's files. If you want to move the VM elsewhere, do not touch the VHD files Hyper-V has stored, use the export function in the Hyper-V Management Console.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want to delete the Rename Base snapshot. This will merge your current state and discard that snapshot. It sounds like you rolled back to the snapshot instead of getting rid of it, which will bring your machine back to the state that it was in when it was snapped.

You might want to read some technet articles/blogs about Hyper-V snapshots. They've very powerful, but can be a nightmare if you don't know what you're doing.